# Assign "ID" to a string in a "post"

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have a file with the following format:

```
"<POST N> 

sentences

<POST N>

other sentences..."
```

Where N is the ID of the POST (the number varies and it's not always 1,2,3...)

I need to create a dictionary with this format: {word: set([IDs])} since some words may be contained in more than one post, but I cannot really understand how to assign multiple numbers to the same word.

Here's the code until the point I got stuck:

The output should be like:

{u'word1: [set([ID])]
u'word2: [set([ID, ID ID])] *<--- if the word is contained in more than one post*
...
}

PS. Here's what the function "words" does, but it does not have anything to do with my problem

```
def noalpha(s):
    noa = ''
    for c in s:
        if not c.isalpha() and c not in noa:
            noa += c
    return noa
def words(s):
    noa = noalpha(s)
    for c in noa:
        s = s.replace(c, ' ')
    return s.split()
```

---

EDIT:

Thanks for your help (anyway I decided not to use your code because I just stared studying python and it looks too much advanced for me), anyway the code ins't complete and I got stuck again:

What the code should do more is, for each word "l", fill another set dw, that is if len(iw) isn't < 3. In that case, if "l"'s "iw" is a subset of that word's iw, "l"'s dw should be filled with that word
Example:

```
u'replace': [set([]), set([1, 2, 4, 5])],
u'for': [set([u'replace']), set([1, 2, 4])]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand what your edit is about. Please show a more complete example (with input text, where do `"replace"` and `"for"` come from?)

Comment: I solved the problem by myself, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this part, where you overwrite the values for word `kk` in each iteration of the inner loop when it appears in more than one post `s`.

```
for s in dizv:
    for kk in dizv[s]:
        dnew[kk] = set([s])
```

Instead, you can use `setdefault` to create a new `set` if it does not exist already and otherwise just `add`to that set.

```
        dnew.setdefault(kk, set()).add(s)
```

---

Also, you can use regular expression for matching the `<POST N>` lines and finding words, and use a `defaultdict` to make the entire code a bit more compact:

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    index = collections.defaultdict(set)
    num = None
    for line in f:
        m = re.match(r"<POST (\d+)", line)
        if m is not None:
            num = m.group(1)
        else:
            for word in re.findall(r"\w+", line):
                index[word].add(num)
```

Comment: Anyway, I shall ask you again if you could help me further (see the EDIT).